# Ant exec refactoring

Tags: ant, refactoring

I've this code in my build.xml:

```
    <exec executable="cmd" osfamily="winnt">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="xsltproc\bin\xsltproc.exe"/>
        <arg value="--xinclude"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg value="dist/html/main.html"/>
        <arg value="xsl/html/docbook.xsl"/>
        <arg value="xml/main.xml"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="xsltproc" osfamily="unix">
        <arg value="--xinclude"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg value="dist/html/main.html"/>
        <arg value="xsl/html/docbook.xsl"/>
        <arg value="xml/main.xml"/>
    </exec>
```

the  sequence is the same... I'm wondering about how refactoring this small fragment in order to keep it DRY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe try using a property for the common bits with arg-line? something like this:

```
<property name="xslt.common" value="--xinclude -o dist/html/main.html xsl/html/docbook.xsl xml/main.xml"/>
<exec executable="cmd" osfamily="winnt">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="xsltproc\bin\xsltproc.exe"/>
    <arg line="${xslt.common}"/>
</exec>
<exec executable="xsltproc" osfamily="unix">
    <arg line="${xslt.common}"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 6):

Define a [macro](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

You can glob the shared portions in an element, and conditionally execute the specific parts.

Comment: This is an excellent solution if you have to perform the same task more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** the Unix version will work under NT if you have the xsltproc.exe available in via the PATH environment variable.  You could try removing the osfamily and see.